# Returning Array names in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to call the names of the arrays in an array of arrays? I am applying a Luhn algorithm to a set of credit card numbers in an array of arrays I would like output that says, 'Array xxx is true/false.' I have created a workaround below by creating an array of "names" but can the batch array names be accessed directly?

```
// All valid credit card numbers

const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5,5,3,5,7,6,6,7,6,8,7,5,1,4,3,9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers

const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// Can be either valid or invalid

const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above

const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5]
const arrNames = ['valid1', 'valid2', 'valid3', 'valid4', 'valid5', 'invalid1', 'invalid2', 'invalid3', 'invalid4', 'invalid5', 'mystery1', 'mystery2', 'mystery3', 'mystery4', 'mystery5']
const batchL = batch.length;

function ValidateCred(CC) {
      if (CC.length > 19) return (false);
      sum = 0;
      mul = 1;
      l = CC.length-1;
    for (i = 0; i < l+1; i++) {
            digit = CC[l - i];
           tproduct = digit * mul;
     if (tproduct >= 10) sum += (tproduct % 10) + 1;
       else sum += tproduct;
      if (mul == 1) mul++;
       else mul--;
    };

    if ((sum % 10) == 0) return (true);
        else return (false);
      };

  for (b = 0; b < batchL; b++) {
  console.log('Card', arrNames[b],'is: ', ValidateCred(batch[b]));
  };
```

Comment: if you want to havw name for the array(s) you should store it in object (as dictionary) or Set

Comment: Why not use Object that has properties as arrays? `valid = {valid1: [], valid2: []}`, then you can have name of property

Comment: You should rather not have `valid1`, `valid2` etc. here - _those_ should be elements of an array _already_. Every time you start “numbering” variable names, you should automatically think, hey does this not belong into an array instead to begin with …?

Comment: Thank you. I will try these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach to this problem is to use an object instead of an array:

```js
const validCCNumbers = {
  valid1: [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8],
  valid2: [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9],
  valid3: [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6],
  valid4: [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5],
  valid5: [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6]
}
```

If you need to access the names of each array you can do it with `Object.keys(validCCNumbers)`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the whole operation considerably:

```js
const all= {valid1:["4539677908016808", "5535766768751439", "371612019985236", "6011144340682905", "4539404967869666"],
          invalid1:["4532778771091795", "5795593392134643", "375796084459914", "6011127961777935", "5382019772883854"],
          mystery1:["344801968305414", "5466100861620239", "6011377020962656203", "4929877169217093", "4913540463072523"]};

Object.entries(all).forEach(([grname,arr])=>{
  console.log(grname);
  console.log(arr.map(cc=>cc+": "+ValidateCred(cc)));
});

function ValidateCred(ccstr) {
  if (ccstr.length > 19) return (false);
  let CC=ccstr.split(""), digit, tproduct,
      sum = 0, mul = 1, l = CC.length-1;
  for (i = 0; i < l+1; i++) {
      digit = CC[l - i];
      tproduct = digit * mul;
    if (tproduct >= 10) sum += (tproduct % 10) + 1;
    else sum += tproduct;
    if (mul == 1) mul++;
    else mul--;
  };
  return sum % 10 == 0
};
```